# Can't find bundle error when running in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have this project that I downloaded. At first, I opened it as an existing Android Studio project but the run button was greyed out. I went to the edit configurations but there was a no module selected error but there wasn't an option to select module.

So I imported the project instead. But this error popped up. I already sync project with `Gradle` files and it didn't help either? I even upgraded my Android from 3.0.1 to 3.1

**Pic of error**

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've had a similar, quite not same, error when I started using Android Studio. I couldn't solve it unless I downgraded Android Studio to the 2.x version instead of 3.x. You should try and see if that helps.

Comment: I downgraded it before and there were even more errors relating to sdk?

Comment: Did you properly uninstall Android 3 before installing Android 2?

Comment: are you using multiple string.xml for multilingual support??

Comment: No I only have one string.xml

Comment: I just realised when I import the project my build gradle files are missing?

Comment: Also specifically which android studio version are u using?

Comment: Did you import as a Gradle project? Did you select the build.gradle file instead of the folder when you did? At the moment, it just looks like you opened the folder, in Android Studio, not as an application. Personally, I use Intellij, not Android Studio

Comment: Omg this saved my life thank youu